# How to disable inspection on files in dist folder

Tags: webstorm

Most of my JavaScript projects have a folder `lib` containing source files and a folder `dist` containing builds of the project.

I use WebStorm (great IDE!), and WebStorm's code inspector and code navigation always reckons with both sources and build files. For example when clicking "Goto declaration" on a method, instead of going to the declaration I first have to select the right one from two or three options: the source file, the library, and the minified library (the latter via the source map I guess).

To solve this, I can mark the `dist` directory as "Excluded", but then the folder isn't visible at all in the IDE, not even for the version control system so I can't easily commit changes to github.

Is there a way to disable inspection of the files in the folder `dist` without making the folder completely invisible for everything in the IDE?

Edit:

I found the same question for PHPStorm: [How to exclude files/folders from code inspection in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129857/how-to-exclude-files-folders-from-code-inspection-in-phpstorm). The provided answer works: create a scope where `dist` is excluded, then for each individual inspection add the created scope and remove the default scope (there are hundreds of inspections...). However this is so extremely cumbersome and error-prone that its hardly worth it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding scopes to inspections won't help with 'goto declaration' issues
I can suggest the following: 
- in Settings/javascript/libraries, add `dist` folder as a library 
- disable this library

Does it help? See also [IDEA-23537](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537)